# Weird GRE mistake

Tags: gre-exam

According to the answer key, the correct answer is (a)....  This is obviously a mistake, right?  If a square matrix is invertible, then it has full rank.

[image]

Comment: Well B, C, D and E are all equivalent, and B implies A, but not vice versa.

Comment: But is a saying it has full rank?

Comment: Nope, it is not. :)

Comment: @SihOASHoihd This might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6734/gre-linear-algebra-question

Answer (score 9):

The columns can be pairwise independent without being independent as a set.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$